# Alternative to "Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);"

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

Creating a basic input and gridview page in ASP.NET. On the page the user inputs data and they can see it on the gridview and all is good but I was wondering if there was an alternative to `Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);` (this is the final line of code that's used to submit the users input) because this does restart the page and some custom stuff they might have done (like hide or view certain options) will restore back to default.

Ideally, the user should be able to input data, submit and view it and the page does not restart.

In case you want to know what the C# code is like, it's below this line...

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (ButAc.Text == "No")
    {
        con = new SqlConnection(@"MY CON SOURCE");
        con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("SQL COMMAND"), con);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action", Action.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Acc1", Acc.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Acc2", Acc2.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
}
```

Comment: Don't do that? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Server.Transfer is one alternative

Answer (score 0):

Not really understand, but maybe one of:
1) not use Response.Redirect at all (current page will be shown)
2) also use IsPostBack

Comment: Hm, can you give an exmaple of IsPostBack?

Comment: Idea: 
1st page load - called Page_Load with IsPostBack = false;
2nd.... page loads - for ex button clicked - called Page_Load and after - button's click method. With IsPostBack=true. Initial control values should be set 1st time